# edit the template to have two sidebar instead of one

Tags: templates

How can I edit the "Protostar" template in order to have two sidebar instead of only one on the right? You can also edit the width of each sidebar?

I would try to edit the index.php file of the template but it is better to ask first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Module Positions**

To see all the module positions, set Extensions -> Templates -> Options -> Preview Module Positions to "Enabled" and browse to:

www.yourwebsitename.com/index.php?tp=1

To enable the left hand sidebar in ProtoStar, publish a module to `Left [position-8]`.

To enable the right hand sidebar in ProtoStar, publish a module to `Right [position-7]`.

**Sidebar Widths**

Unfortunately, you can't specify sidebar widths via the ProtoStar options in Template Manager.

A custom CSS file at /templates/protostar/css/user.css with the following code (or similar) could be used to override the sidebar and main content widths:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar.span3 {width: 20%;}  /* Left Hand Sidebar */
  #content.main {width: 60%;}   /* Main Content */
  #aside.span3 {width: 20%;}    /* Right Hand Sidebar */
}
```